# STM32L4xx float numbers way off

Tags: c++, stm32

It is known that `float`and `double` are not always accurate, but this does usually gets to decimal spaces. In my application, the number is not in the range of any usuable result

this function receives a uint32_t out of an array

```
volatile uin32_t adc3 =  hw_ADC_Get(position)
```

Since this is an integer and the output should be in volts, it must be converted to a float value. this is done by:

```
// divide reference by range, 3000mV/4096bit
float c_factor = float(3000)/4096.0;
// multiply the measured range number by the factor to get the voltage
float v_in = c_factor * float(adc3); 
//multiply voltage with voltage divider ratio, to get real voltage
float v_real = 1.823529179354124 * v_in;
```

a result from debugging turns out the following

```
adc3 = 2767
c_factor = 0.737281859
v_in = 540095319  (should be 2040.05)
v_real = 944263180 ( should be 984’879’573.82 inherited from v_in error)
```

therefore two float operations seem to fail dramatically, first v_in and then v_real.

The described problem is occuring on a STM32L4xx Series Microcontroller.

What could be the cause/solution for this behavior?

Comment: Sorry, what does `float(x)` function do?

Comment: Thats not a function. thats standart data convertion, its possible to to this with any type uint8_t(x) etc.

Comment: Have you tried `v_in = c_factor * (float)adc3; `?

Comment: Do you use Hard or Soft FPU and are you running an OS like FreeRTOS?

Comment: yes, i also tried to insert a hard coded number for adc3, which results in the same.
@veeman i'm not running any os, run my code directly on the mcu. Im unsure what fpu, i did not configure anything about fpu.

Comment: Your IDE, if you use any, should provide some settings about the FPU. Usually you have two options to use Sofware FPU or Hardware FPU, if the device supports Hardware FPU. Check this settings. If you use Hard FPU you also need to enable it. Also if you calculating with only floats i recommend to use the postfix "f" for your constants. At least some debuggers have problems to interpret floating numbers, try to assign the result back to an integer value and check if it makes sense.

Comment: Your c_factor is already off by 1%. It should be 0.732421.
What happens if you type constexpr float c_factor = 3000.0f / 4096 ?

Comment: Are you printing/logging the values to the a console for debugging, or are you stepping through the code with a debugger connected to the hardware to inspect the actual variable contents?

Comment: i found out that its using hardware fpu. I'm using the debugger and set a breakpoint AFTER the calculation. This issue seems to be a compiler issue. I've now disabled all optimisations and made assigned the float to a uin32_t. When i did this, the uint32_t came out correct, and the inserted float is also correct!! I now will try to validate this with a display unit, not via the debugger.

Comment: Nice, let us know where the problem came from, if you find out, sounds interesting! (IMHO it is often better to use the debugger to see what's really going on, than to use printf-like logs - at first I thought your issue actually comes from such a *printf() formatting problem...)